# How to resize controls to fit the browser window in C#, Silverlight 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, resize, tabcontrol

I have a tab control in my main page.  When I have it in the Design view in Visual Studio, everything looks perfect, the tab control is set to fill the entire page.  However when I run the program, and I have it in a maximized browser window, the tab control is still the same size as it originally was.  In other words, the tab control does not resize proportionally to the browser window resize.

So I was wondering if there was a way to change a setting on my tab control or maybe some code that would force the tab control to resize along with the browser window?

(Using C#, Silverlight 4.0 in VS2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after tinkering with this for the last couple days, I've finally found the answer.  I feel like a rookie for not doing this sooner, but I got to looking at the title bar on the top of the page and noticed that it stretched across the screen when the browser window was maximized and when it was resized, the title bar shrunk to fit.  So I looked at the properties of the title bar and saw that it's horizontal/vertical alignment was set to "stretch."  I know, it's a rookie mistake, but it just never occurred to me that "stretch" was an option in the alignment property.

Long story short, change the horizontal alignment property to "stretch," vertical alignment property to "stretch," and then set the height property of the control to "auto" and the width property to "auto" and you've got yourself an auto-resized control.